# With OpenLayers is there anyway to keep existing features whilst adding more on each refresh?

Tags: openlayers-2

Currently I use a Cluster strategy and a Refresh Strategy and get KML data from a url.

The KML data plots points on a vector layer and the cluster strategy groups close features together.

At each refresh interval the features are removed and new data is read from the server.

This is currently working.

What I want to do is the same as the above but when the refresh occurs I don't want the existing features to be removed. Instead I want the new features to be added to the existing features and the clusters to be recalculated.

I've spent a couple of days trying to find out how to do this but am failing miserably at the moment.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either use a middle-man server which collects the data, or you'll want to use localStorage or IndexedDB to store data in the browser.

IndexedDB is probably the better choice because it can store much more data. Cross-Browser support is sort of goodish with basic support available in all major browsers (though with bugs reported in several implementations)

More about IndexedDB:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API#Storage_limits

More about localStorage:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Comment: I meant that IndexedDB is the better choice for client-side storage. If you can set up a middle-man server to collect the data that would give you more control and reliability.